# docker error Unable to locate package cowsay

Tags: docker

When I am running the build command:

```
$ docker build -t cowsay .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM
Unknown instruction: FROM
dev@ub:~/cowsay$ docker build -t cowsay .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 90d5884b1ee0
Step 2 : RUN apt-get -y install cowsay
 ---> Running in 587aaba2824b
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package cowsay
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install cowsay' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Content of Dockerfile is as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get -y install cowsay
RUN apt-get -y install fortune
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/games/cowsay"]
CMD ["Docker is so awesomoooooooo!"]
ONBUILD RUN /usr/games/fortune | /usr/games/cowsay
```

How can I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and add `RUN apt-get update` first.

Once the packages are updated, you can install, for instance, cowsay.

See for instance [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/mbentley/docker-cowsay/blob/master/Dockerfile) as an example of `RUN apt-get` commands:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cowsay
COPY docker.cow /usr/share/cowsay/cows/docker.cow

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/games/cowsay","-f","docker"]
CMD ["moby","dock"]
```